# How to read all the lines using CSV in Python?

Tags: python, csv

In my case, I'm creating a register and it needs to store the login credentials into an external file, through using CSV.

I have 2 problems:

1. **Every login (username and password) except the first one doesn't
   work.** My first login "*14JeoJun*" username and "*seagull*"
   works, but the next one "*13ParJim*" username and "*excuseme*"
   password doesn't, as well as the rest afterwards. I assume this is because it has not read all of the lines.
2. **It wont loop the code for 3 times and close afterwards.** It will just forever loop it if you keep getting it wrong, even the login credentials that aren't the first but correct. If the first login credential is correct then it stops looping and exits. I assume this is because of the first problem above.

   ```
   with open("login_credential.txt","r") as login_credential:
   for x in range (0,2):
       inputted_username = input("Please enter your username - ")
       inputted_password = input("Please enter your password - ")
       login_credentialReader = csv.DictReader(login_credential)
       for lines in login_credentialReader:
               if lines["username"].lower() == inputted_username and lines["password"].lower() == inputted_password:
                   print("Welcome...")
                   sys.exit()
               elif lines["username"].lower() != inputted_username or lines["password"].lower() != inputted_password:
                   x += 1
                   print("Login credentials are incorrect. Please try again.")
                   login()
       if x >= 3:
           print("Too many incorrect tries...")
           sys.exit
   ```

This is what's in my external file (login_credential.txt):

*username,password,forename,surname,year

14JeoJun,seagull,Jungkook,Jeon,2014

13ParJim,excuseme,Jimin,Park,2013

10KimNam,gotjams,Namjoon,Kim,2010*

Whenever I switch around whichever comes first, only the first will work.

Comment: reading a csv file is such a standard problem; why don't you use pandas, this will be much easier to deal with data, as you can do everything in a vectorized way insted of these loops?

Comment: @Magellan88 it looks like it is school assignment

Answer (score 0):

After reading the file once, the filehandle gets closed, you cannot read from it again. In particular, look here:

> ```
> with open("login_credential.txt","r") as login_credential:
>     for x in range (0,2):
>         inputted_username = input("Please enter your username - ")
>         inputted_password = input("Please enter your password - ")
>         login_credentialReader = csv.DictReader(login_credential)
>         for lines in login_credentialReader:
>             # ...
>
>         # ...
> ```

On the second iteration of the `for x in range(...)` loop,
the filehandle `login_credential` has already been fully read,
it will not be re-read again,
so the body of the inner for-loop will not be executed.

There are other serious issues with this code as well.
For example, in a `for x in range(...)` loop,
you should not modify the value of `x` inside the loop body.
It will probably not work as you intended,
because on the next iteration `x` will reset to the next value coming from `range(...)` anyway. Don't do this.

A minor issue, look at these conditions:

> ```
> if lines["username"].lower() == inputted_username and lines["password"].lower() == inputted_password:
>     # ...
> elif lines["username"].lower() != inputted_username or lines["password"].lower() != inputted_password:
>     # ...
> ```

The second condition is the opposite of the first.
That's pointless, you could replace the long `elif` with a simple `else`.

---

As per the general approach,
instead of re-reading the password file on each retry of the username/password by the user,
it might be better to read the lines of the file only once, and reuse it.
That will require more memory, but save on I/O.
It's probably a good tradeoff.

It could something like:

```
with open("login_credential.txt","r") as login_credential:
    login_credentialReader = csv.DictReader(login_credential)
    lines = [line for line in login_credentialReader]

for x in range(2):
    inputted_username = input("Please enter your username - ")
    inputted_password = input("Please enter your password - ")

    # ...
```

Comment: While this is a good answer per se, I would say that it does too much, as  providing complete solution for school assignment code is not in the best interests of student (who seems at the moment to struggle with basic understanding of his own code), according to FAQ https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @Gnudiff I agree with your intention, but I'm not sure I gave away too much. I think that's subjective. But I took your advise and rewrote the answer, doing more explaining and handing over less code on a silver platter.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing currently is checking each line, if it matches AND if it does not.

What you **need** to do is to only check line, if it matches and if it does not - try the next line. Only if no line in the file  matches, you need to say about wrong credentials -- that  line goes after  the loop.